# How can I avoid a join in SQL and still relate values across tables

Tags: sql, performance

I am trying to find how many users visit our site within 30 days after they make their first purchase, but the tables are large and the query times out when I try to join them (I'm working in a restricted reporting environment), which I need to do to restrict it to only the visits on days after the purchase. So if User A visits on 2021-05-01, makes a purchase on 2021-05-02, and visits again on 2021-05-10 I want to record that as one post purchase visit.

This is the query that times out:

```
FirstPurchases as (
  Select
    *
  From (
    Select
      Id, UserId, PurchaseDate, min (PurchaseDate) Over (Partition By User) as first_purchase_date
    From PurchaseHistory
  )
  Where
    PurchaseDate = first_purchase_date
    and PurchaseDate between [start_date] and [end_date]
),
With Visits as (
  Select
    UserId, VisitDate
  From DailyVisitHistory -- only one visit per user per day is recorded
  Where VisitDate between DATEADD(dd,1,[start_date]) and DATEADD(dd,30,[end_date]) -- excludes same day visit, which will always exist
  Group by UserId
)


Select
  p.UserId
  , v.VisitDate
From FirstPurchases p
 left join Visits v
 on p.UserId = v.UserId
Where 
  v.VisitDate > p.PurchaseDate
```

From what I can tell, the visits table is very large and the execution times out trying to join the tables.

I've tried looking at even just 1 day post first purchase, but the start_date to end_date range needs to be a month and then I'm looking at ~30 days of visits (depending on the month), and I can't figure out a way to make this more efficient or avoid the join.

Comment: All users visit within thirty days after they make their first purchase, assuming that the purchase is onsite.

Comment: @GordonLinoff users can make a purchase and not return to the site. Shipment status and other info about the purchase is sent over email, there's no reason they have to come back to the site unless they want to do more shopping.

Comment: . . You missed my point.  The original purpose is within 30 days of the original purchase.

Comment: You seem to pull bizarrely large amounts of data out of your tables when all you say you want is a count..

Comment: @Gordon, are you speaking to the point addressed in the SQL with the comment "excludes same day visit"?

Comment: @CaiusJard I suppose I could count visits per user to see if a non-zero amount exist in the visits table, should make the visits table a lot smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work out:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM
  (SELECT UserId, MIN(PurchaseDate) as mindate FROM PurchaseHistory WHERE PurchaseDate BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date GROUP BY UserID) FP
WHERE
  EXISTS(
    SELECT null FROM DailyVisitHistory v
    WHERE v.UserId = FP.UserId AND v.VisitDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day,1,v.mindate) and DATEADD(day,30,v.mindate)
  )
```

I'd expect you'll need indexes on PurchaseDate in PH and at least userid (but preferentially UserId+VisitDate) in DVH